# How to get Profile picture of User Friend's ??

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Actually (I am Able to Get  User Friend's" Name  & ID " But can't get Profile Picture of User Friend's )  This Code take The Friend List and After  I Display the User Friend Name , ID , Picture (Picture Don't Display But It not Work )

```
            <?php
            try {
    $requestFriends = $fb->get('/me/taggable_friends?fields=id,name,picture');

            }           
// Get the Friend List and Store them as a Key Value pair

/// Here The Story Start I am Able to Get  User "Friend Name  & ID " But can't get Profile Picture of User Friend's         /////
            foreach ($friendsArray as $key) {
              {
                     echo $key['name'] . "<br>"; 
                 echo $key['id']."<br>";
echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $key['id'] . '/picture"/>';

              }
            }
?>
```

Comment: Well Brother Yes I want to tag But Before tag I want to Get picture of User Friend's

Comment: may be your friend not made profile picture public so you can see the image. i am not sure. because same url i get the image. i tried this id=20226877432

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not get an actual ID, you only get a "tagging token". Check out the returned JSON, the picture URL is already in there:

```
{
  "id": "xxxxx",
  "name": "xxxxx",
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/12115682_11736....."
    }
  }
}
```

For example:

```
echo '<img src="' . $key['picture']['data']['url'] . '"/>';
```

Comment: I found this also But its also not working Your mean i have to Access Url Rather then ID ?? 


Code Here -->>> 

$friendlist = $facebook->api('/me/friends/');

foreach($friendlist["data"] as $value) {
    echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $value["id"] . '/picture"/>';
}

Comment: /me/friends gets you only a list of friends who authorized your app too, it works different. with non-app-friends, you need to use taggable_friends, and you don´t get any ID, only a tagging token for tagging. just use the picture urls in your json result. (picture > data > url)

Comment: i have updated my answer. untested, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks Sorry i comment after so many time ! But at that time i was not active User 
Thanks Sir

Answer (score 0):

I want to improve luschn's answer.

Just use

```
echo '<img src="' . $key['picture']['url'] . '"/>';
```

instead of

```
echo '<img src="' . $key['picture']['data']['url'] . '"/>';
```